# Call backup endpoint in case get promise fails

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-promise

I have a method returning a promise that either resolves or rejects.

```
myMethod() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      axiosClient
        .get(endpoint)
        .then((response) => {
          resolve(response.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          reject(error);
        });
    });
  }
```

Is there a way to return another promise in case this produces an error, calling a backup endpoint?? Something along the lines of:

```
myMethod() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  axiosClient
    .get(endpoint)
    .then((response) => {
      resolve(response.data);
    })
    .catch(() => {
      axiosClient
        .get(backupEndpoint)
        .then((response) => {
          resolve(response.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          reject(error);
        });
    });
});
```

Edit: if this is a duplicate I have not been able to find something about it that is specific to this point. Could it be because it's a bad practice?

Edit2: thanks for the answers, maybe I should clarify better the flow I want to achieve:

get endpoint -> (if this fails) get fallback endpoint -> (if this fails aswell) reject the entire promise

Comment: [What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743) | [Aren't promises just callbacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22539815)

Answer (score 0):

From the above, one could simplify it doing with re-usability best practices,
as follows:

```js
myMethod() {
  const PromiseHandler = url => {
    /**
    * this function recevies url
    * makes the request and return
    * a reposne form the end point
    */
    return axiosclient.get(url).then(res => res.data)
  }
  
  return PromiseHandler(endpoint)
    .catch(() => {
      return PromiseHandler(backupEndPoint)
}
```